# Error connecting to Hornetq from Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, queue, jms, jmx, hornetq

I'm having this error when I have a standalone Hornetq running I'm trying to connect to it from tomcat. I get this error :

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.hornetq:module=Core,type=Queue,address="jms.queue.MyQueue",name="jms.queue.MyQueue"
       com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)
   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:662)

com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:638)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an attribute from an instance which is really not there. What I would suggest don't call getAttribute on Instance of it is null. While you are trying queryName(or) queryMBeans you will know whether Mbean exists or not.